# Presentation page before launching main activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want my application to show a presentation page for 2 seconds for instance when the user click on it.

So far I made an other activity with a frameLayout which has an Image. I load this activity, I try to make it sleep for 2 seconds, then I send an intent to the main activity.

It doesn't work very well, it doesn't feed the first activity with the background image if I do the Thread.sleep() thing.

My question is : how do I perform to do that properly, because I think I'm on the wrong path.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT SOLUTION : I solved this just by using the handler thing in my presentation activity, in where I launch the main activity after 2 seconds. Thanks guys.

Comment: just use `popupwindow` for Presentation page and launch it for first time when your main activity started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Thread.Sleep`, in your `onStart` do this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // launch your other activity here.
    }
}, 2000); // 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another activity, and its sole purpose is to show this Image. You then call this image, and create a `Handler` with a `postDelayed()` to finish that Activity, and load your new one.

So this is your flow:

Activity A-> ActivityB(Presentation)->Activity C

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example "Android Splash Screens Done Right"

http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/

I like this way because you don't waste 2 seconds, that seconds are used to do other stuff.